# Only keep rows if any values between certain columns meet a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

Im looking for a way to subset my dataframe. It is 92 columns and about 2000 rows.
I need to keep only rows that (in the last 50 columns of the dataframe) contain a value between -30 and 30 in any of the columns.

All the columns that need to meet this condition start with the string 'daysbetween' so I tried the following:

```
data <- crf1 %>%
  filter(if_any(starts_with("daysbetween"), ~ . > -30 &  ~. < 30 ))
```

but I got the following error:

```
Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `... | daysbetweenV1312 > -30 & (~ . < 30)`.
Caused by error in `daysbetweenV21 > -30 & (~ . < 30)`:
! operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
structure(list(V1 = c("00006", "00009", "00013", "00017", "00040", 
"00042", "00043", "00051", "00061", "00068"), V2 = structure(c(18750, 
18745, 18753, 18922, 18898, 18925, 19018, 18726, 18977, 18766
), class = "Date"), V3 = structure(c(18917, 18904, 19146, 18922, 
18898, 19018, 19196, 18959, 18946, 18945), class = "Date"), V4 = structure(c(18823, 
18905, 19275, 19187, 19219, 19134, 19331, 18885, 18922, 19275
), class = "Date"), V5 = structure(c(18972, 19185, NA, NA, NA, 
19349, 19289, 19063, 19149, 18400), class = "Date"), V6 = structure(c(19352, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19035, 19028, NA), class = "Date"), V7 = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19197, NA, NA), class = "Date"), V8 = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19411, NA, NA), class = "Date"), V9 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), V10 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), V11 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), V12 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), V13 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), V14 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), daysbetweenV21 = structure(c(167, 
159, 393, 0, 0, 93, 178, 233, -31, 179), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    daysbetweenV22 = structure(c(73, 160, 522, 265, 321, 209, 
    313, 159, -55, 509), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Columns V1 to V14 dont have to be filtered, only the columns starting with 'daysbetween' are relevant.

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: ```cfr %>% dplyr::filter(if_any(starts_with("daysbetween"), ~between(as.numeric(.), -30, 30)))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added an extra "~":

```
data <- crf1 %>%
  filter(if_any(starts_with("daysbetween"), ~ . > -30 &  . < 30 ))


# V1         V2         V3         V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10  V11  V12  V13  V14
# 1 00017 2021-10-22 2021-10-22 2022-07-14 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#   2 00040 2021-09-28 2021-09-28 2022-08-15 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#   daysbetweenV21 daysbetweenV22
# 1         0 days       265 days
# 2         0 days       321 days
```

Expanding a bit "~" tells R you're typing an anonymous function, so the call must be made only once, then you can use the . / .x syntax afterwards without issue

Comment: This is a typo. I would personally not provide an answer to this. Maybe a comment and then casting a CV. Cheers.

Comment: Didn't know about the typo close vote. Voted to close it too